# Change inheritance tree of DBIx Class Result classes?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

G'Day,

I'm working with DBIx::Class 0.07003 and DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader 0.03009 and I'm trying to change the base class of the classes generated by the Loader -- from:

```
package S2S::DBIxperiment::Productions;

# Created by DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader v0.03009 @ 2011-06-24 14:29:13

use base 'DBIx::Class';

__PACKAGE__->load_components("PK::Auto", "Core");
```

to something like:

```
package S2S::DBIxperiment::Productions;

# Created by DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader v0.03009 @ 2011-06-24 14:29:13

use base 'BaseMooseDBI';

__PACKAGE__->load_components("PK::Auto", "Core");
```

where BaseMooseDBI looks like:

```
package BaseMooseDBI;

use Moose;

use base qw(DBIx::Class);
```

However, this does not seem to work at all, and it doesn't seem to inherit stuff from `BaseMooseDBI` package (attributes, etc.) I tried overriding `load_components` in `BaseMooseDBI` as well, but it never gets called - instead it errors that it cannot find `load_components`?

What seems to be the problem?

Note: I cannot use the newer `use_moose` and `result_base_class` when generating the result classes.

EDIT: Found the solution. Saw the how DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader does it *now*, have Mutable and Immutable result classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to add a few methods, etc. to the parent class, your code should work. You might need to `use MooseX::NonMoose`, and in the past I have had the parent subclass `DBIx::Class::Core` instead of `DBIx::Class`. Here is what I've used successfully:

```
# Parent
package App::Schema::Result;
use Moose;
use MooseX::NonMoose;
use namespace::autoclean;
extends 'DBIx::Class::Core';
sub parent_method { ... }

# Child
package App::Schema::Result::Product;
use Moose;
use MooseX::NonMoose;
use namespace::autoclean;
extends 'Keystone::Schema::Site::Result';
__PACKAGE__->table('products');

sub child_method {
   my ($self) = @_;
   $self->parent_method();
}
```

If you want the parent class to define `DBIx::Class` specific information (ie, call `__PACKAGE->table`, `__PACKAGE__->add_columns`, etc) take a look at `DBIx::Class::Helper::Row::SubClass`. Using it, you define the parent class as you would a normal `DBIx::Class::Result::*` and in the child class use the `SubClass` component and call `subclass`:

```
# Parent
package App::Schema::Result::Parent;
use Moose;
use MooseX::NonMoose;
extends 'DBIx::Class';
__PACKAGE__->load_components(qw{InflateColumn::DateTime Core});
__PACKAGE__->table('products');
...
# Child
package App::Schema::Result::Child;
use Moose;
use MooseX::NonMoose;
extends 'App::Schema::Result::Parent';
__PACKAGE__->load_components(qw{Helper::Row::SubClass Core});
__PACKAGE__->subclass;
# Now add the child specific stuff / override parent stuff
```

I'm not sure if you can get `Loader` to auto-generate some of this code.